# ProcessBar counter C#

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a question about the ProcessBar on C#,
How would I add the value of 1 to a label if the method used when passing an item within a list box was successful ?

I have a method like this

```
private static  Form1 f1 = Application.OpenForms["Form1"] as Form1;
public static void GroupList1(processBar bar)
{
 f1.listBox1.Items.Add("User1");
 bar.Value = 100;
}

public static void GroupList2(processBar bar2)
{
 f1.listBox1.Items.Add("User2");
 bar.Value = 100;
} // Etc, etc - up to GroupList6
```

I would also like to have a label that tells me how many user's were successfully added (using the bar), I was thinking of adding a method like this :

```
if (bar.Value = 100)
{
  f1.label1.Text = "" + 1; 
}
```

Inside of my GroupList1/2 method, but the label always appears as the value 1 .

This method within the main form of my code loads a separate label :

```
for(int i = 0; int i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{ 
 label2.Text = i.ToString();
}
```

So, I would like label 1 to increase by 1 if the user has been loaded into my list box successfully, how would I do this ?

Obviously this isn't actually the code I'm using within my program, a method is used if the selected index changes (which is why I want to increase by 1, to ensure the user parsed the method successfully), but the question still remains as described, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont quite understand well what are you trying to achieve, but if you only look in increasing the value of such label then you can easily do this by

```
if (bar.Value = 100)
{
  f1.label1.Text = ""+(int.Parse(f1.label1.Text)+1); 
}
```

or even a better way to initialize the string if for some reason the Text of the label is not an integer

```
if (bar.Value == 100)
     {
       int value;
        if(!int.TryParse(f1.label1.Text,out value))
         {
           f1.label1.Text = "1";
         }
        else
        {
             f1.label1.Text = ""+(value+1); 
        }
     }
```

but the best way to do this is to keep track of the value in a separate variable and just update the content of the label.

Comment: This method also works flawlessly, great answer ! =D

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea to store the actual count in the label's `Text` property, instead, create a variable:

```
private static int count;
```

Now, change your code to something like this:

```
if (bar.Value = 100)
{
    // Add 1
    count += 1; 
    // Update the UI
    f1.label1.Text = count.ToString(); 
}
```